# Free from memory an array of struct

Tags: c

I have the following function.I think free(temp) is not freeing all allocated memory.When I give NULL to these three fields, my program works fine.When I give regular values to them, my program is killed by Linux after 20 minutes of normal IO operation.For the 20 minutes, my program, at first, runs fast, and gets slow before it is killed. So I guess I should free the fields' allocation also or something other is happening? The fields are char*.

```
void traverseAlignLList()
{
Node1 *temp;  
struct Node *old_node;
int temp_counter=0; 
int i;
cur_node=start_node;
temp=malloc(alignCounter*sizeof(Node1));
while(cur_node!=NULL)
{               temp[temp_counter].template_id=malloc((strlen(cur_node->template_id)+1)*sizeof(char));

 strcpy(temp[temp_counter].template_id,cur_node->template_id);  


  temp[temp_counter].target_sequence=malloc((strlen(cur_node->target_sequence)+1)*sizeof(char));

  strcpy(temp[temp_counter].target_sequence,cur_node->target_sequence);
  temp[temp_counter].template_sequence=malloc((strlen(cur_node->template_sequence)+1)*sizeof(char));

  strcpy(temp[temp_counter].template_sequence,cur_node->template_sequence);

  temp_counter++;

  old_node=cur_node;
  cur_node=cur_node->next;

  free(old_node);



  addAlignData(temp);


  free(temp);
  temp=NULL;

  start_node=NULL;
}
```

Comment: Where is free(temp) called? Which 3 fields are you referring to?

Comment: Have you tried using a memory-checker such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?  Debugging tools such as this are very beneficial to know, especially for larger projects.

Comment: Every single thing that you malloc has to have a corresponding free.  You malloc temp and then you malloc target_id and then you malloc target_sequence twice so when you are one with that memory you need to free it - in he case of target_sequence you need to free it before you amlloc it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free memory for array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823308/free-memory-for-array-of-structs)

Answer (score 0):

As C has no notion about which pointers were allocated and which ones cone e. g. from static memory, you'll have to explicitly free everything you `malloc()`ed before. Otherwise you have a memory leak.

E.g., if the contents of a `Node1` are

```
.template_id=malloc((strlen(cur_node->template_id)+1)*sizeof(char));
.target_sequence=malloc((strlen(cur_node->target_sequence)+1)*sizeof(char));
.template_sequence=malloc((strlen(cur_node->template_sequence)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

you'll have to later free them again.

With a mere `free(old_node)` or `free(temp)`, you'll lose the pointers while the memory still remains allocated.

Similiarly, you have to free everything under the same condition as you free it.

If you `malloc()` your `temp`, and then skip over the `while` loop, you'll lose it.

Answer (score 0):

free() does not know about other pointers to malloc'd memory inside of the pointer being free'd.  free() takes a void * as an input parameter, so free() doesn't event know about the type of struct being de-allocated.

You need to free all other memory in temp before freeing temp.